# asp.net ".d" failure parsing JSON on client side

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json

The configurations to my asmx page are as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Services;
using Time.CSharpclasses;
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for LiquidityMonthAjax
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class LiquidityMonthAjax : System.Web.Services.WebService
```

On the client side my response is mysteriously coming back with a different type of item I have never seen before, even though I use the same methods to parse it to JSON.

```
#document
 <string xmlns="tempuri.org">
["Presbyterian Health","Devon","LABS","Self-Pay","Sagamore"]
  </string>
```

I don't understand what's different. I usually get my json from .d.

Using Asp 4

There must be some dependency I'm missing but I dont know if it is client side or server.

```
[WebMethod]
        public string getUniqueFinClass()
        {

            DataTable dt = ExcelManager.CreateDataTableFromSql(new XMLManager("liquiditymonth.xml").getReport(Xmls[6]));
            var r = from row in dt.AsEnumerable() select (string)row["FinancialClass"];
            return DictToJSON.serializeJSONObject(r.ToList());
        }
```

The former is the method that gives me problems the serializeJSONObject method 
follows:

```
public static String serializeJSONObject(Object items)
    {
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new

       System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.MaxJsonLength = 2147483644;




        return serializer.Serialize(items);
    }
```

I really don't think is that method that's the problem because I've used it a hundred times before with success.

Comment: You should show whole webservice method and also what you have in response.d so someone can help you.

Comment: response.d is undefined

Comment: You need to define class and return it.

Comment: @mybirthname you mean like have a new object returned instead of packing the json myself and letting [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] do it for me? Or something else?

Comment: Yep the best way is to create new object as class I will post you an example. Also you need to add another attribute to the method.

Comment: What happen is my code help you ?

Comment: I'll try on Monday. Back to work.

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of the .Net platform return `d` some do not.  Try putting something like this in your code:

```
var data = (response.hasOwnProperty("d")) ? d : response;
```

Now `data` contains the response no matter which version of .Net is being used making your client code more robust.

Dave Ward did a blog on this: http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was client side. I forgot to stringify my object so jquery politely wrapped the aguments up in the url query instead. A function of ASP.net says that if the request is not JSON then the response is XML forsaking the request header type and any attempt of the programmer to make it JSON. 
Refer to this link under JSON,Objects and Strings: oh my!

http://encosia.com/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/